# Udunits2 installation in python

Tags: python, python-iris

I am working on some climate data simulations for which I need conservative remapping algorithm. This algorithm is available in cf-python library. But cf python requires udunits2 package as one of its dependencies. On searching a lot, I found that the source files for udunits2 are written in C. I also found a python wrapper [here](https://github.com/jr3cermak/robs-kitchensink/tree/master/python/udunits) but was unable to run it because of missing vcvarsall.bat file.
I found this [discussion](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/udunits/msg00661.html) saying that python module for udunits2 is available but the link doesn't work.

Can anyone please guide me to some simple steps on how to install udunits in python?
I'm trying to use iris and cf python libraries for climate data simulation and both of these libraries require udunits2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Iris and its dependencies is with Conda.  There are instructions here:
https://scitools-iris.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html#installing-using-conda-users

cf-python also has instructions for installing with Conda here:
https://ncas-cms.github.io/cf-python/installation.html#conda